# Handling large vector illustrations

Tags: java, android, memory, out-of-memory, vector-graphics

I have implemented three **vector images** in my app each one is assigned with a different `cardview` but their size is too big and android couldn't handle it and every time I build and/or run the app I get a `OutOfMemoryException` another thread suggested that I should add this code to my manifest

```
<application
    android:largeHeap="true"
</application>
```

After doing that the app builds and runs successfully but is **lagging** when I scroll the cardviews.

**Q:** What is the best way to get rid of this **lag** ?

**XML File**

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.hivemind.user_feed.Activities.IndexActivity">
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:background="@color/blue4"
    android:id="@+id/cardsContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/hotel_card"
        style="@style/MyCardViewStyleContent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageHotels"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/hotel" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Hotels"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="HOTELS"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:textColor="#333"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/resto_card"
        style="@style/MyCardViewStyleContent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageResto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/restaurant" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textResto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="RESTAURANTS"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:textColor="#333"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/clinic_card"
        style="@style/MyCardViewStyleContent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageClinic"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/clinic" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textClinic"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="CLINICS"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:textColor="#333"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the **JAVA class**

```
public class IndexActivity extends Activity {

private CardView HotelCard;
private CardView RestoCard;
private CardView ClinicCard;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_index);

    HotelCard = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.hotel_card);
    RestoCard = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.resto_card);
    ClinicCard = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.clinic_card);

    HotelCard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            goto_Hotel_List();
        }
    });

    RestoCard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            goto_Resto_List();
        }
    });

    ClinicCard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            goto_Clinic_List();
        }
    });

}

public void goto_Hotel_List(){
    /*Intent H = new Intent(this, HotelActivity.class);
    startActivity(H);*/
}

public void goto_Resto_List(){
    /*Intent R = new Intent(this, RestoActivity.class);
    startActivity(R);*/
}
public void goto_Clinic_List(){
    /*Intent C = new Intent(this, ClinicActivity.class);
    startActivity(C);*/
}
}
```

Comment: and cannot you replace them with raster bitmaps?

Comment: also see [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html) ^F `Considerations for SVG and PSD files`

Comment: @pskink excuse my ignorance but I never worked with any kind of images before and I am really lost I would appreciate it if you guide me through it

Comment: just export your svg (i believe your vector files are in svg format) to png/jpg/webp format

Comment: Actually two of them are .jpg and one is .png

Comment: so what [vector graphics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics) do you mean? i am lost actually...

Comment: They are made with illustrator and actually I exported them and them as .jpg/.png before importing them to my peoject in Android Studio

Comment: so what size are they (in pix)? and on what size do you want to draw them (display size in pix)?

Comment: They are: 1/ 1300x1300 (128 kb) .jpg 2/1280x960 (185 kb) .png 3/1400x980 (89.5 kb) .jpg and I want to draw them the width is set to match parent and height is 200 dp and I have a property `scaleType="centerCrop"`

Comment: weird, they are not that big... where did you place them? what subfolder in `res ` folder? see https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Just in drawables like any ordinary image

Comment: try `res/drawable-nodpi` folder, also see https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html and read about resource auto scaling

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by simpling passing the assets through photoshop and reducing the size

**P.S.** After the process you might lose some of the image's high quality (it depends)